# Weird XAML errors after upgrading WPF app to .NET 5

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-5

I have a XAML view that I created in a .NET Framework WPF app, and I'm trying to upgrade the app to .NET 5:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:AutoPBW="clr-namespace:AutoPBW;assembly=AutoPBW"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Shell;assembly=PresentationFramework"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="window"
        x:Class="AutoPBW.WPF.MainWindow"
        Title="AutoPBW" Height="397" Width="653" Loaded="window_Loaded" Closing="window_Closing" Icon="AutoPBW.ico">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- this CollectionViewSource gives a null reference exception on the d:DesignSource attribute -->
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="playerGameViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type AutoPBW:PlayerGame}, CreateList=True}"/>
        <Style x:Key="ListItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!-- this ControlTempate gives an error saying that the Item.MouseOver.Background resource could not be found -->
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <!-- here is where the Item.MouseOver.Background resource is actually referenced -->
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
       <!-- this is where the actual UI is defined, no errors here -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I have removed a few irrelevant sections, but the comments denote where I encountered compile errors.

The errors I see are:

> XDG0062 Object not set to an instance of an object.

and

> XDG0062 Cannot find resource named 'Item.MouseOver.Background'. Resource names are case sensitive.

How can I solve these errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I figured it out. I had my TargetFramework set incorrectly in my project file. It should have been `net5-windows`, but I had it set to `net5.0-windows`.